# binary decision diagram

Tags: java, binary-decision-diagram

In Java, I have set of expressions like cond1 AND (cond2 OR cond3) AND ( cond 4 OR cond5). I would like to convert it into tree and then evaluate the final boolean answer. I tried searching a lot around java BDD but not able to get any. Any suggestion with sample code ?

Comment: I think this BDD is Behaviour Driven Development. good luck with your question - I don't have a clue :)

Comment: Do you want to evaluate an expression and get the results matching the expression? That's more like @Jochen's answer then anything to do with binary decision diagrams.

Answer (score 4):

A 5-second [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+%22binary+decision+diagram%22) returned some reasonable-looking results:

- [JavaBDD](http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/)
- [Java Decision Diagram Libraries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaddlib/)
- [What is the best Binary Decision Diagram library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579263/what-is-the-best-binary-decision-diagram-library-for-java)

Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: Btw, also: https://github.com/johnyf/tool_lists/blob/master/bdd.md

Answer (score 3):

He means Binary Decision Diagrams.

I've been tinkering with [JavaBDD](http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/) and [JBDD/JDD](http://javaddlib.sourceforge.net/jbdd/).  Both are based on BuDDY (a C library) -- JBDD actually uses the C DLLs for a marginal performance boost.

It looks to me like JavaBDD is more fully-featured (ex. it supports composing BDDs, which is what I need).  But there is also no tutorial for it, and while the class docs aren't terrible, frankly I can't figure out how to use it for the most basic of boolean operations (like the problem you pose).

JBDD/JDD requires you to use manual garbage collection, and does weird things like store BDD objects in Java integers -- clearly carry-overs from C.  But it has a set of tutorials.

Comment: Update: This weekend I wrote a simple (and doubtless inefficient) BDD library, source code available [here](https://github.com/SigmaX/LightBDD).  I haven't had time to make it presentable (i.e. write a nice readme and/or tutorial), and it's only been moderately tested, but it could be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your own parser, check out JavaCC. 
Here is a nice tutorial to get you started. A bit older, but still valid:

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-cooltools.html